# How to controll Gmaps in ZK MVVM

Tags: java, spring, google-maps, zk

Please need help about integrate google map in zk using MVVM,  [My REfrence](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/reporting/google_map) in MVC, the problem is how to adding marker and controll to move focus on my coordinate i've set lat lng in `@Init()` and bind to Gmarker in zul but nothing happen.
Here is my [ViewModel](https://www.pastiebin.com/5c9d3cec19737) and [my ZUl](https://www.pastiebin.com/5c9d3c317f5d0)

Comment: For "nothing happen" do you mean you could not see the marker? First of all, add an attribute open=true in marker.

Comment: sorry for late respon, here is my code :
`@AfterCompose
    public void aftercomp(){
    gmaps=new Gmaps();
    gmaps.enableBindingAnnotation();
    lat=-6.206040;
    lng=106.818771;
    Gmarker marker=new Gmarker();
    marker.setLat(lat);
    marker.setLng(lng);
    marker.setOpen(true);
    gmaps.appendChild(marker);
    gmaps.focus();    
    }`
but still no marker appear.

Comment: if i am add marker in zul like this `<gmaps id="gmaps" width="100%" height="500px"  >  
                                              
                            <gmarker  lat="@bind(item.latitude)" lng="@bind(item.longitute)" >

                            </gmarker>
                    </gmaps>`it working, but i want to populate marker from database